# WPF Binding TwoWay DataGrid

Tags: wpf, database, binding, two-way-binding

i am making simple wpf project, have to connect to DB and bind it to DataGrid.
The thing is: i can display data from DB, but i cannot update it back. I've been looking for answers, tried 100 different things, i do not know what can it be.

My xaml data grid:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridData, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0"    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    </Grid>
```

My View

```
    class View
    { 
        SqlConnection con;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("emp");
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlCommandBuilder builder;
        public DataView GridData
        {
            get
            {

                con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=MAXMAD-\R;Initial Catalog=WOC;Integrated Security=True");
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string Get_Data = "SELECT * FROM Player";

                    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = Get_Data;

                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error occured, can not connect to db!");
                    return null;
                }
                return dt.DefaultView;
            }
            set
            {   
                da.Update(dt);
            }
        } 
    }
```

code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            View myView = new View();
            DataContext = myView;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, i do not know why, but the set GridData is not getting called, so i added a delegate:

```
dt.RowChanged+= new DataRowChangeEventHandler(delegate(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs args) { da.Update(dt); });
```